# Android pass Fragment parameter instead of List into ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-sqlite

from the WebServer i can fetch data and pass it correctly into ListView with this class:

`ReceiveFields` class Structure:

```
public class ReceiveFields {
    public long lastId;
    public String smsNumber;
    public String mobileNumber;
    public String senderName;
    public String smsBody;
    public String receiveDate;
    private Context ctx;
}
```

`ReceivedSMS` Class to get data from WebService:

```
public class ReceivedSMS extends ListFragment implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    private List<ReceiveFields> rows;
    private int prevVisibleItem;
    private TSMS tsms;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    public  Long getLastReceivedSMSID;
    private boolean isFirstTime;
    private Context context;

    public ResivedSMS(Context context, String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ResivedSMS(String username, String password, long start, long count,Context context) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.context = context;
        tsms = new TSMS(context ,new User(username, password));
        getResivedSMS(start , count);
    }

    public ResivedSMS(List<ReceiveFields> receivedSMSList,Context context){
        rows = receivedSMSList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public List<ReceiveFields> getResivedSMS(long start, long count) {
        tsms = new TSMS(context,new User(this.username, this.password));
        try {
            rows = tsms.getReceivedSMS(start, count);
        }
        catch (TException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ERROR IN Fetch SMS From WebService List<ReceiveFields> getResivedSMS(long start, long count) " , String.valueOf(e));
        }
        return rows;
    }
```

use ResivedSMS class as :

```
ResivedSMS receivedSMSList = new ReceivedSMS("username","password",0,20,context);
```

and pass into ListView :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.drawer, receivedSMSList).commit();
```

all of this way is correct and i dont have problem. but i want to fetch data from DataBase and pass it insted of ReceivedSMS as :

```
List<ReceiveFields> r1 = db.getAllReceivedSMSFromDatabase();

receivedSMSList = new ResivedSMS(r1,context);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.drawer, receivedSMSList).commit();
```

`getAllReceivedSMSFromDatabase` function :

```
public List<ReceiveFields> getAllReceivedSMSFromDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.RECEIVE_FIELDS_TABLE ;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    List<ReceiveFields> ListSMS = new ArrayList<ReceiveFields>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        ListSMS.add(new ReceiveFields(
                Long.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastId"))),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("smsNumber")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mobileNumber")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("senderName")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("smsBody")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("receiveDate"))));
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return ListSMS;
}
```

NOTE: My Database is not empty and have 20 rows

`getAllReceivedSMSFromDatabase` return value is like with `getResivedSMS` but i get this error :

[image]

`getAllReceivedSMSFromDatabase` Function Result with `LogCat:

```
ID: 19  lastId: 29901991  smsNumber: 30007227  mobileNumber: 09000000892  senderName 09122510892  smsBody: tsssasaS  receiveDate: 2014/8/3

ID: 19  lastId: 29901992  smsNumber: 30007227  mobileNumber: 09000000892  senderName 09122510892  smsBody: tsssasaS  receiveDate: 2014/9/3

ID: 19  lastId: 29901993  smsNumber: 30007227  mobileNumber: 09000000892  senderName 09122510892  smsBody: tsssasaS  receiveDate: 2014/10/3
```

Comment: Your setting the list object, while it requires the fragment, initialize and set your fragment class ReceivedSMS here.

Comment: @jitainsharma i can't do it. how to?

Comment: Like ReceivedSMS receivedSMS = new ReceivedSMS(context, username, password);

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are passing a list as argument to [replace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment)) and it is expecting a Fragment as parameter.

> public abstract FragmentTransaction replace (int containerViewId, **Fragment** **fragment**)

You have passed a list as an argument instead of passing a Fragment.

Try passing **ReceivedSMS** ( which `extends ListFragment`) instead of **ListSMS** which is a list (`List<ReceiveFields> ListSMS`)

Comment: I dont underestand me sir. can you paste correct way to post? –  TuxWorld 21 mins ago

Comment: @TuxWorld Repeating that oh so many times is not the best approach to go about getting help... Moreover, your timestamp is in your message already, yet you copied that as well.